# Invertibility of an operator involving inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inverse

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with basis $b_i$. For all $t$, let $f(t;\cdot,\cdot)$ be an inner product on $H$.
For each $j$, is
$$\int_0^T \sum_{i=1}^\infty f(t,b_i,b_j)x_j(t)=0$$
uniquely solvable for $x_j$, given that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(t,b_i,b_j)x_j(t)=0$$
is uniquely solvable for each $t$? (This second displayed equation is not given to hold by the way).

Basically I want to show that $x_j=0$ for all $j$.

We have that $t \mapsto f(t;\cdot,\cdot)$ is integrable.

Comment: Can you proofread this? There are references to $y_j$ and $w_j$ which are never used again. Also, you probably want some more conditions on $f$ and $x_j$ to guarantee that the integral exists.

Comment: Thanks Nate I removed bad references.